# What is the purpose of isNull()?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

from underscore:

```
_.isNull = function(obj) {
    return obj === null;
  };
```

why would you want to use this method instead of just using

```
obj === null
```

Comment: I don't feel this is opinion based as there is a clear answer - For use in callbacks so that the library user does not have to write it again.  Can we please re-open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `_.isNull` can be passed as a function argument while `obj === null` would have to be wrapped in a function to do so, meaning using `_.isNull` saves you the time of having to wrap that statement in a function yourself.

Comment: @www.arcmarks.com [Yes](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/functor), but it seems I used it wrong. You would pass `_.isNull` to a functor rather than it being a functor itself.

Comment: I feel this is a good question/answer can you ask the moderators to open it up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to the change log, it is there "for completeness."

> 0.4.7
>
> Added `isDate`, `isNaN`, and **`isNull`, for completeness.** Optimizations for `isEqual` when checking equality between Arrays or Dates. `_.keys` is now 25%–2X faster (depending on your browser) which speeds up the functions that rely on it, such as `_.each`.

Comment: well why not `isFalse` and `isTrue`?

Comment: @www.arcmarks.com because the isFoo functions are mostly about detecting *type*, not *value*. isTrue and isFalse would deal with booleans (there is already isBoolean); isNull deals with nulls.

Comment: `null` is a value of type `Null`

Comment: @www.arcmarks.com, if you add isTrue and isFalse, do you also add isOne, isTwo, isThree...?

Comment: `NaN` is a value of type `Number`

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said "mostly" ;)

Comment: Actually, there's no need for `isTrue` because it already exists in JavaScript. Just use `Boolean` as a function (assuming you're testing the truth value of an object and not whether the value is strictly equal to `true`, that is.)

Answer (score 2):

Syntactical sugar, standardization, and a much smaller chance of accidentally typing `==`, so much less error-prone coding.

Answer (score 1):

Probably for use in iterator methods, like `.some()`.

```
var has_null = collection.some(_.isNull);
```

It's nice to have reusable functions for somewhat common purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The `_.isNull` function doesn't seem to have much use other than for callbacks, so it might just be there for completeness. When you look in the [Underscore.JS source code](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1039;L1062), you can see that the other similiar functions aren't that trivial:

```
// Is a given object a finite number?
_.isFinite = function(obj) {
  return isFinite(obj) && !isNaN(parseFloat(obj));
};

// Is the given value `NaN`? (NaN is the only number which does not equal itself).
_.isNaN = function(obj) {
  return _.isNumber(obj) && obj != +obj;
};

// Is a given value a boolean?
_.isBoolean = function(obj) {
  return obj === true || obj === false || toString.call(obj) == '[object Boolean]';
};

// Is a given value equal to null?
_.isNull = function(obj) {
  return obj === null;
};

// Is a given variable undefined?
_.isUndefined = function(obj) {
  return obj === void 0;
};
```